# How to run Grunt task on save inside NetBeans 8.0?

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I'm working on a typical Maven Spring MVC project inside NetBeans 8.0 where front end development is done in AngularJS. Since I have over 30 .js files already and they are growing I decided to use Grunt to merge and minify those files.

I have installed Node.js, npm and grunt-cli and have manually installed grunt (via npm) at the root folder of my project and everything is working as expected. What I'm doing now is running grunt manually from the console to build those files.

What I would like to do is automate this process and have grunt run each time I press save button. I'm trying to achieve exact thing how less and sass preprocessors work inside netbeans. You just setup "watch" folders and on each save less or sass runs and compiles files down to css.

Comment: You probably know that (and it is not exactly what you asked for), but if you fail to find a way to do it in NB, you could always use `grunt-contrib-watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the watch function: [grunt-contrib-watch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch). Like any other watcher it will trigger a process (grunt in your case) every time a file in the watched path is changed.